# shell script on mac to ssh path / CD in a dir

Tags: macos, terminal, script

I am looking for a way to  in terminal

```
cd into dir1    
Then in a new tab 
cd into dir2    
Then in a new tab 
cd into dir3    
Then in a new tab 
cd into dir4    

Then in a new terminal window 
ssh into path1 and 
then in a new tab 
ssh into path 2 etc
```

is there a way I can create a script or a shortcut for cd-ing /  sshing  on a mac?

I thought I can create a script.command file and in that write 
`cd path 1`

but that does not work. I get a message `process competed` and then it exits

Comment: So basically you want to open 6 tabs, four of them with the shell running in a specific local directory, and two of them with an ssh session, correct?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13018/opening-a-terminal-window-to-a-specific-directory-from-a-bash-script?rq=1 looks like a good start